is there a way to get a value without side effects out of another case?
I have this code. I want to find a way to extract the type of arguments that were fed into the Function and and give them to insert function so I can use them later in type checking for function calls.
I tried using a case but surely that wasn't enough since Haskell doesn't provide for-loops. so I didn't go far.
at the moment I can think of using State monad probably as a solution but I don't know if that's even going to be useful for me here.
I'd be glad if someone will be kind to give me a way.

data TypeT
  = UnitT
  | BoolT
  | FloatT
  | IntegerT
  | StringT
  | ListT TypeT
  | FunctionT [TypeT] TypeT
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Statement
  = Block [Statement]
  | Function String [Statement] TypeT Statement -- Function name arguments type body
  | FunctionArg String TypeT -- Argument name type
  deriving (Show, Eq)


typeCheckStmt :: Scope -> TypeT -> Statement -> State (SymbolTable, SymbolTable) ()
typeCheckStmt scope returnType =
  \case
    Function name args type_ body -> do
      -- a new scope for variables in symbol table
      let newScope = scope + 1
      -- here I want to collect types of arguments of function and put them in `typeArgs`
      typeArgs <- traverse (typeCheckStmt newScope type_) args
      -- then insert the function with the signature into symbol table
      _ <- insert name (FunctionT typeArgs type_) scope
      -- and the rest of the type checking
      _ <- typeCheckStmt newScope type_ body
      exitFunction
    FunctionArg name type_ -> do
      -- each argument is added to the symbol table of that function
      _ <- insert name type_ scope
      pure ()


Why is the list of arguments a [Statement]? Why is FunctionArg String TypeT a statement? This looks weird to me, it's have expected something like [(String, TypeT)] so to avoid arbitrary statements ending up in the list of formal arguments.

"I tried using a case but surely that wasn't enough since Haskell doesn't provide for-loops. so I didn't go far."
I'm confused by what you mean here. You're matching on args here. You already have the types of the args, what do you want to "get", and why do you think you need a for loop? Your traverse of course doesn't give you anything because your typeCheck isn't returning anything

@chi your comment is the solution to my question I guess. thank you.
